# I don't know how to add the Facebook SDK to my Android Cordova project

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I see a lot of links that describe how to add the SDK via a plugin. I do not want to add any plugin.

I am using the command line and Windows 7.

I just want to know the steps to add the SDK without a plugin, and without Eclipse.

I basically need this working, for tracking installs from Facebook ads:
`com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, facebook_app_id);`

I don't know where to get the library files for that, or what the name of the library file is, or what else I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

here is the library you need to use FacebookSDK on your cordova project --> https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.

Althought, the best way to install and configure it is using cordova commands --> http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: The aim is to get ``com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp`` working without a huge library..

Comment: In other words, nothing in what you posted helped in any way. But I still upvoted... "A" for effort.